# The separation symbol could not be found Unexpected data found. Trailing data Carbon Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm using carbon in my laravel project. I tried to change date format following. I can't find any error but it is showing separation symbol could not be found.
This is how I have done

```
$employees = $request->get('employeeIds');
    $inTimes = $request->get('inTime');
    $outTimes = $request->get('outTime');

    $attendance_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->get('attendance_date'))->format('Y-m-d');

    //fetch employee working hours
    $workTimes = Employee::where('status', AppHelper::ACTIVE)->get()->reduce(function ($workTimes, $employee) use ($request) {
        $workTimes[$employee->id] = [
            'in_time' => null,
            'out_time' => null
        ];
        if ($employee->duty_start) {
            $workTimes[$employee->id]['in_time'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $request->get('attendance_date') . ' ' . $employee->getOriginal('duty_start'));
        }

        if ($employee->duty_end) {
            $workTimes[$employee->id]['out_time'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $request->get('attendance_date') . ' ' . $employee->getOriginal('duty_end'));
        }

        return $workTimes;
    });
```

Comment: Watch out, the solution you validated works for m/d/Y, not for d/m/Y, please precise: which line throws the error and provide static data sample as we can't guess the content of `$request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this issue by using **strtotime** function :

```
$attendance_date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($request->get('attendance_date')) )->format('Y-m-d');

//fetch employee working hours
$workTimes = Employee::where('status', AppHelper::ACTIVE)->get()->reduce(function ($workTimes, $employee) use ($request) {
    $workTimes[$employee->id] = [
        'in_time' => null,
        'out_time' => null
    ];
    if ($employee->duty_start) {
        $workTimes[$employee->id]['in_time'] = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($request->get('attendance_date') . ' ' . $employee->getOriginal('duty_start')) );
    }

    if ($employee->duty_end) {
        $workTimes[$employee->id]['out_time'] = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($request->get('attendance_date') . ' ' . $employee->getOriginal('duty_end')) );
    }

    return $workTimes;
});
```

Comment: `Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime())` is equivalent to `Carbon::parse()`

Comment: But this won't work for your format `d/m/Y` as `Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime('02/03/2020'))` gives you February 3, not March 2.